# How do I write a condition within an SQL Select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a rather long SQL query to pull some values out my database written inside a stored procedure. I am passing an IN parameter called pupiltype which will either =0 or =1.

If the pupiltype value=1, I need the line a line in my query to be:

```
 AND tbl_4.status=1
```

but if the pupiltype value is 0, it needs to be:

```
 AND (tbl_4.status=0 OR tbl_5.ID IS NOT NULL)
```

I can put a condition around my whole query, but this means duplicated lots of other lines of code which feels unneccersary. Is there a way of putting this conditional statement inside the SQL statement itself just around this one line to run different AND statements?

For example...:

```
WHERE tbl_1.sID=sID
    AND tbl_2.spID=spID 
    AND tbl_3.progress!=''
    AND tbl_4.status=1; // It's this line I need to be varied...
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
( (pupiltype = 0 and tbl_4.status = 1) or
  (pupiltype = 1 and (tbl_4.status = 0 OR tbl_5.ID IS NOT NULL))
)
```

Comment: Thanks - I will give it go.

Comment: I think this is missing parentheses.  I think you'll get results if pupiltype = 0 and tbl_5.ID is not null.  So (a = 1 and b = 0 or c is not null) should be (a = 1 and (b = 0 or c is not null))

Comment: @dougp . . . I think you are right.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff take a break, let some little guys answer some questions :)

Comment: Thanks Gordon - It works and makes sense. Good to know you can reference the IN statements within the SQL query itself.